# Why isn't my PHP form working? I do receive the email but there is no content in it

Tags: php, html, css, forms, phpmyadmin

PHP form on my website isn't responding well. It would be appreciated if someone could help me.

This is the **HTML Code** of the form

```
<form action="contactform.php" method="post" name="form" class="p-5 bg-white">
    
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 mb-md-0">
            <label class="text-black" for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="text-black" for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="text-black" for="email">Email</label> 
            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="text-black" for="subject">Subject</label> 
            <input type="subject" id="subject" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="text-black" for="mssg">Message</label>
            <textarea name="mssg" id="mssg" cols="30" rows="7" class="form-control" placeholder="Write your notes or questions here..."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary py-2 px-4 text-white">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the **PHP Code**

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $to = "alyyashar@gmail.com";
    $subject = "New email from your site!";
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    
    $title = '<h3>Hello! You have received a new mail from your website!</h3>';
    
    $body = "$title
            <br/>
            <b>From:</b> $fname
            <br/>
            <b>E-Mail:</b> $email
            <br/>
            <b>Message:</b>\n$message
            <br/>
            <br/>";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){
        echo "<h1>Sent Successfully! Thank you"." ".$fname.", We will contact you shortly!</h1>";
    } else { 
        echo "Something went wrong!";
    }
}
?>
<br>
<a href="/">Back to Homepage</a>
```

This is the email I receive

[Screenshot of the email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IuoC.png)

When I enter information into the form and click send message, I do receive the email but there is no content in it.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form elements have no `name` attributes, which is what the browser uses to send their name/value pairs to the server.  So while it's posting the form, none of the values are being included.

For example, this:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control">
```

Should be this:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control" name="fname">
```

The same fix would need to be repeated for the remaining form elements.